# Update progress inside update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

i have two buttons inside a update panel.i need to trigger update progress and show a .gif image for each button click.when i press a button1 only the associated update progress should be displayed and the other one should be invisible

Comment: Take a look at this very good article explaining step by step [Using UpdateProgress Control Effectively in ASP.Net AJAX](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/125_Using_UpdateProgress_Control_Effectively.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

After a long search, trial and error, i've come up with something that worked for me.

You'll need to combine some Javascripting and dual panels in your update panel.
**Please note this is done in VB.NET 

Please note that my example is using masterpages 

Please note that the ID's of the buttons and panels are hardcoded (not ideal)**

This is the codebehind..

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        registerscript()
    Else
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub registerscript()

    Dim clientscriptname As String = "popup"
    Dim clientscripttype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
    'checck if clienscript is already registered, if not register it
    If Not (cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(clientscripttype, clientscriptname)) Then

        Dim myscript As New StringBuilder
        myscript.AppendLine("<script language=" & Chr(34) & "javascript" & Chr(34) & " type=" & Chr(34) & "text/javascript" & Chr(34) & ">")
        myscript.AppendLine("        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();")
        myscript.AppendLine("        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);")
        myscript.AppendLine("prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);")
        myscript.AppendLine("var postBackElement;")
        myscript.AppendLine("function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {")
        myscript.AppendLine("postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel2').style.display = 'none'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel4').style.display = 'none'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("if (postBackElement.id == 'ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Btn1') {")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel2').style.display = 'block'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel4').style.display = 'none'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("                                                                  }")
        myscript.AppendLine("else                                                               ")
        myscript.AppendLine("                                                                  {")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel2').style.display = 'none'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel4').style.display = 'block'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("                                                                  }")
        myscript.AppendLine("}")
        myscript.AppendLine("function EndRequest(sender, args) {")
        myscript.AppendLine("if (postBackElement.id == 'ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Btn1') {")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel2').style.display = 'none'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("           $get('ctl00_ctl00_Centerofpage1_Main_Panel4').style.display = 'none'; ")
        myscript.AppendLine("}")
        myscript.AppendLine("}")
        myscript.AppendLine("        </script>")
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(clientscripttype, clientscriptname, myscript.ToString, False)

    End If
End Sub
```

This is the main aspx page .

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Title" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
<cc1:toolkitscriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</cc1:toolkitscriptmanager>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UPL1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"   >
<ContentTemplate >
<asp:Button ID="Btn1" runat="server" Text="Test1"   />
<asp:Button ID="Btn2" runat="server" Text="Test2"  />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UPG1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UPL1"  Visible="true"  >
<ProgressTemplate >
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="overlay" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" CssClass="loader" runat="server" >
            .BTN1 : form posting in progress.
                    <br />
                    <asp:Image ID="LoadImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Masterpages/images/updateprogress/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" CssClass="loader" runat="server"  >
            .BTN2 : form posting in progress.
               <br />
                    <asp:Image ID="LoadImage2" runat="server" ImageUrl="../Masterpages/images/updateprogress/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
</asp:Content>
```

The javascript code will intercept the postback operation for the updatepanel and hide or show the respective panels accordingly.

Cssclass=Overlay and CssClass=Loader are some CSS styles to make the page opaque and postion the feedback in the middle

Pressing button1 ...

[image]

Pressing button2
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can associate the UpdateProgress  control with a single UpdatePanel  control by setting the progress control's AssociatedUpdatePanelID  property. In that case, the UpdateProgress  control displays a message only when a postback originates inside the associated UpdatePanel  control.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx