# How to progressbar on button click?

Tags: asp.net

After clicking on button,entry should go into database.In that time interval ,I want to show processing to user.I used updateprogress for that.I have selectAll checkbox(selectedIndexchange event) in same page.when check selectAll, it shows progress bar.I don't want that.I want only on button click.In updatprogress mention displayafter =0

Answer (score 1):

Would using an update panel and a Update Progress control be suitable?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386421.aspx

[Update progress inside update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254774/update-progress-inside-update-panel)

If you wanted more control I would personally use this Jquery control to show a progress panel http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/ and then use Ajax calls to the server

Comment: I used inside table's <td> first updateprogress and after that update panel.but metion associate panel in update progress.On every autopost ,it show progress bar.Page have gridview and one button outside grid.But both in a same pannel.Inside the grid,select all checkbox,is there.Even that checkbox event also,it is showing.I don't want that